# Hide / show lower-case characters

Tags: css

Using just CSS is it possible to hide/select the lowercase characters of a string?

```
<p>Richard Parnaby-King</p>
```

To show only `RPK`?

Using `::first-letter` I can show only the letter `R`. Is there any way to expand on this?

```css
p {
  font-size:0;
}
p::first-letter {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<p>Richard Parnaby-King</p>
```

#### Edit

The intent is to animate the letters out. i.e. have a css animation that starts as `RPK` and expands to `Richard Parnaby-King` on hover.

I am not able to alter the html.

My current thinking is to change the font colour of the `p` tag to white (on white background), create an `:after` element with the content "RPK" centred on the `p` tag and on `:hover` animate rotate the "RPK" 90 degrees then `display:none` it (or something so that it is not visible), rotate the `p` tag to 270 degrees and animate rotate it to finish at 360 degrees. The final effect is "RPK" rotating around and "Richard Parnaby-King" coming out of it. Below I have "sort of" the effect I have described above but it doesn't hide/show the text correctly.

```css
p {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
p:after {
  content: "RPK";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color:#000;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}
p:hover {
  animation: pSpin 1s forwards;
}
p:after:rhover {
  animation: pAfterSpin 0.5s forwards;
}
@keyframes pSpin {
  0% {
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    color:#fff;
  }
  50% {
    color:#000;
    transform:rotateY(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    color:#000;
  }
  
}
@keyframes pAfterSpin {
  0% {
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    color:#000;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotateY(90deg);
    color:#fff;
    z-index:-5
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Richard Parnaby-King</p>
```

Comment: Nope. CSS can't select text-nodes and thus it can't style them.

Comment: CSS is not your answer, try using php or javascript.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Any special reason to use `PHP` instead of any other server-side language?

Comment: You **might** be able to so something with `unicode-range` but it's a lot of trouble for something that's better left to other avenues of approach.

Comment: PHP seems overkill. JavaScript is all you'd need and would be simple.

Comment: Nope, there is a thousand ways to skin a cat. in this case CSS is not one of them, but php is. I just gave a couple of examples of languages that will work, would you like me to list them all?

Comment: The intent is to animate the letters out. i.e. have a css animation that starts as `RPK` and expands to `Richard Parnaby-King` on hover.

Comment: @Richard Parnaby-King: Then you would have to define *hiding* and *expanding* these letters for the purposes of the animation. It is rather difficult to instruct the browser exactly how to animate the text when all you have is an element node containing a text node. This is why CSS alone will not be enough to accomplish the desired effect - you will need JavaScript and perhaps a little bit of DOM mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my question I have managed to get this animation working, in which the lower-case text is initially hidden then, on hover, is shown. It is not exactly as I had hoped it to be (I didn't want the text to rotate, but it is close enough).

I am using a series of animations. The first is to rotate the `:after` content. Once that is complete rotate the whole `p` tag and animate it's rotation to show the full name.

```css
div {
  padding:1em;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
p:after {
  content: "RPK";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color:#000;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  
}
div:hover p {
  animation: pSpin 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay:0.3s;
}
div:hover p:after {
  animation: pAfterSpin 0.5s forwards;
}
@keyframes pSpin {
  0% {
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    color:#fff;
  }
  51% {
    color:#fff;
    transform:rotateY(270deg);
  }
  52% {
    color:#000;
    transform:rotateY(270deg);
  }
  99% {
    color:#000;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    color:#000;
  }
  
}
@keyframes pAfterSpin {
  0% {
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    color:#000;
    z-index:2;
  }
  99% {
    color:#000;
    z-index:2;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotateY(90deg);
    color:#fff;
    z-index:-5
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Richard Parnaby-King</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change the HTML slightly, you can sort of achieve it. You might have to play around with it a bit more though.

```css
p span {
  font-size:0;
  display: inline-block;
}
p span::first-letter {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Richard</span> <span>Parnaby-</span><span>King</span></p>
```